# Compile a 64bit project with 32bit dll references

Tags: dll, 32bit-64bit

I have cpp project dll that i want to compile for 64bit machines. But, this project has dll references that are 32bits, how do i do this?

Comment: You don't, mixing is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to load a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit process, and execute its code. Details: Lesson 2. [Support of 32-bit applications in the 64-bit Windows environment](https://www.viva64.com/en/l/0002/). See part: Why can't 32-bit DLL's be used in a 64-bit program? Is there a way to evade this limitation?